# How can I apply a MouseHover and MouseLeave to two controls to act as one control?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have two labels in my form which are placed side-by-side to act as one label. When I hover over the labels, I have a function that fades the labels to different colours, which works well. I am trying to apply the MouseHover and MouseLeave event to both labels, so that when I hover over Label1 and move to Label2 (and vice versa), the function doesn't then fade the colour back to the original colour. Currently, moving between the two labels activates MouseLeave followed by MouseHover again in the new label.

I have tried to add both labels to the event trigger, but this hasn't worked. I have also tried placing both labels in a Panel, but that then doesn't trigger the event.

```
Private Sub fadeHeaderIn(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Label1.MouseHover, Label2.MouseHover
    Call fadeLabel("In")
End Sub

Private Sub fadeHeaderOut(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Label1.MouseLeave, Label2.MouseLeave
    Call fadeLabel("Out")
End Sub
```

If the functionality to change the colour of part of the label existed, I'd not need the two labels, so if there is a better way of doing this altogether, I'm happy to do so. Thanks!

Comment: You can paint any section of a control. In this case, you can defined two rectangles that represent the two parts of the Label you want colorize. When `Rectangle.Contains([MousePointer].Location)`, paint the rectangle (corresponding to a section of the Control) that contains the mouse pointer. `[MousePointer].Location` is referenced by the `MouseEventArgs.Location` property of the `MouseMove` event or  `Control.MousePosition`.

Comment: `Cursor.Position` can also be used, in case you need the `Cursor.HotSpot`. Both `Control.MousePosition` and `Cursor.Position` are provided in Screen coordinates, so you have to translate these measures to client coordinates: `[Control].PointToClient(Cursor.Position)`, for example.

Comment: Thanks @Jimi for your response; are you saying it IS possible to paint one side of a label for example? So I could set it so if the MouseHover for a label is triggered, one half of the text `ForeColor` changes, and the other half of the text `ForeColor` changes to a different color entirely?

Answer (score 0):

> I have also tried placing both labels in a Panel, but that then
>   doesn't trigger the event.

That should work.  The panel would act as the boundaries for both labels.  You'll get a MouseLeave, though, when you move from the panel to the labels contained within.  To prevent a false trigger, simply check if the mouse is still within the bounds of the panel.  You can prevent multiple fade ins when moving from label to label by tracking the faded state with a boolean.  It'd look something like this:

```
Public Faded As Boolean = False

Private Sub fadeHeaderIn(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.MouseHover, Label2.MouseHover
    If Not Faded Then
        Faded = True
        fadeLabel("In")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub fadeHeaderOut(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseLeave
    If Not Panel1.ClientRectangle.Contains(Panel1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)) Then
        If Faded Then
            Faded = False
            fadeLabel("Out")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample of what has been described in comments.

The Text of a control (here, derived from a standard Label) is *split* in two sections of the same measure. Each section can have a different color.
The active and inactive colors are custom public properties, they can be set in the designer.

Each section is *tracked*, meaning that the control is *aware* of what side the Mouse Pointer is currently hovering.

The size of the text is measured using the [TextRenderer.MeasureText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext) method. This size is used to calculate the rectangles that include the sections of text.
The [Rectangle.Contains([Point])](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectanglef.contains) method is then used to determine which section of the text the mouse pointer in hovering. `[Point]` is calculated using the [MousePosition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.mouseposition) property, translated to client coordinates using the [Control.PointToClient()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient) method.

When the mouse pointer is moved from one section of text to the other (here, just two sections, more could be defined adding more rectangles), the control is [Invalidated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate), causing a call to the **`OnPaint`** method of the control.
If the mouse pointer is not hovering a section of text, `base.OnPaint(e)` is called (also causing the `Paint` event to raise), which draws the default text with the default color.

In the **`OnPaint`** method, the Graphics region is clipped using the Rectangles that define the text sections. A subsequent call to [TextRenderer.DrawText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.drawtext), setting the [TextFormatFlags.PreserveGraphicsClipping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textformatflags) flag, clips the text in the defined region, so just the section of text that fits in the clipping region is painted.
The [Graphics.ExcludeClip()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.excludeclip) method is used here to define these clipping regions.

The **`TextFormatFlags.ExternalLeading`** and **`TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl`** are also used to replicate the default text rendering, so the custom text is rendered in the same relative position.

This is how it behaves:

[image: Custom Control Label Split Text]

Custom Control Class to test the functionality:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Windows.Forms

<DesignerCategory("Code")>
Public Class LabelSplitText
    Inherits Label

    Private m_Text As String = String.Empty
    Private m_Sections As RectangleF() = Nothing
    Private m_PaintText As Boolean = False

    ReadOnly flags As TextFormatFlags = TextFormatFlags.ExternalLeading Or
                                        TextFormatFlags.PreserveGraphicsClipping Or
                                        TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        ResizeRedraw = True
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property ActiveRectangle As RectangleF
    Public ReadOnly Property ActiveSide As String = String.Empty
    Public Property ActiveColor As Color = Color.White
    Public Property InactiveColor As Color = Color.DimGray


    Protected Overrides Sub OnLayout(e As LayoutEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnLayout(e)
        Me.AutoSize = False
        m_Text = Me.Text
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseEnter(e As EventArgs)
        m_Text = Me.Text
        Text = String.Empty
        m_PaintText = True
        MyBase.OnMouseEnter(e)
        Invalidate()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseLeave(e As EventArgs)
        m_PaintText = False
        Me.Text = m_Text
        MyBase.OnMouseLeave(e)
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseMove(e As MouseEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnMouseMove(e)
        Invalidate()
        If m_Sections Is Nothing Then Return
        Me._ActiveRectangle = If(m_Sections(0).Contains(e.Location), m_Sections(0), m_Sections(1))
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseClick(e As MouseEventArgs)
        Me._ActiveSide = If(m_Sections(0).Contains(e.Location), "left", "right")
        MyBase.OnMouseClick(e)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
        If Not m_PaintText Then
            MyBase.OnPaint(e)
            Return
        End If

        Dim textSize As SizeF = TextRenderer.MeasureText(e.Graphics, m_Text, Me.Font, Me.ClientSize, flags)
        m_Sections = GetTextAreaSections(textSize)
        e.Graphics.ExcludeClip(Rectangle.Round(m_Sections(1)))
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, m_Text, Me.Font, Point.Empty, GetSectionColor(0), flags)
        e.Graphics.ResetClip()
        e.Graphics.ExcludeClip(Rectangle.Round(m_Sections(0)))
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, m_Text, Me.Font, Point.Empty, GetSectionColor(1), flags)
    End Sub

    Private Function GetSectionColor(section As Integer) As Color
        Return If(m_Sections(section).Contains(PointToClient(MousePosition)),
                  Me.ActiveColor, Me.InactiveColor)
    End Function

    Private Function GetTextAreaSections(textSize As SizeF) As RectangleF()
        If textSize.Width > Me.ClientSize.Width Then textSize.Width = Me.ClientSize.Width

        Dim rectLeft = New RectangleF(PointF.Empty,
                       New SizeF(textSize.Width / 2.0F, Me.ClientSize.Height))
        Dim rectRight = New RectangleF(New PointF(textSize.Width / 2.0F, 0),
                        New SizeF(textSize.Width / 2.0F, Me.ClientSize.Height))
        Return {rectLeft, rectRight}
    End Function

End Class
```